# Python Script with Quartiles Failing

Tags: python

I'm receiving some python errors when I try to run a script -- I was wondering if anyone can provide insight into what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to learn on the job and struggling with troubleshooting as a beginner. Would love some expertise if anyone has a moment.

This is an adaption from a script I found here by Joaol correira. https://github.com/joaolcorreia/RFM-analysis

[error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzp8s.png)

code here:

```
    import sys, getopt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def main(argv):
    inputfile = 'sample-orders.csv'
    outputfile = 'rfm-segments.csv'
    inputdate = '2020-07-08'

    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:o:d:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            inputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            outputfile = arg
        elif opt in ("-d", "--dinputdate"):
            inputdate = arg

    rfm(inputfile, outputfile, inputdate)


def rfm(inputfile, outputfile, inputdate):

    NOW = datetime.strptime(inputdate, "%Y-%m-%d")

    # Open orders file
    orders = pd.read_csv(inputfile, sep=',')
    orders['order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(orders['order_date'])

    rfmTable = orders.groupby('customer').agg({'order_date': lambda x: (NOW - x.max()).days,  # Recency
                                               'order_id': lambda x: len(x),  # Frequency
                                               'grand_total': lambda x: x.sum()})  # Monetary Value

    rfmTable['order_date'] = rfmTable['order_date'].astype(int)
    rfmTable.rename(columns={'order_date': 'recency',
                             'order_id': 'frequency',
                             'grand_total': 'monetary_value'}, inplace=True)

    quantiles = rfmTable.quantile(q=[0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
    quantiles = quantiles.to_dict()

    rfmSegmentation = rfmTable

    rfmSegmentation['R_Quartile'] = rfmSegmentation['recency'].apply(RClass, args=('recency', quantiles,))
    rfmSegmentation['F_Quartile'] = rfmSegmentation['frequency'].apply(FMClass, args=('frequency', quantiles,))
    rfmSegmentation['M_Quartile'] = rfmSegmentation['monetary_value'].apply(FMClass, args=('monetary_value', quantiles,))
    rfmSegmentation['RFMClass'] = rfmSegmentation.R_Quartile.map(str) + rfmSegmentation.F_Quartile.map(
        str) + rfmSegmentation.M_Quartile.map(str)

    rfmSegmentation.to_csv(outputfile, sep=',')



# We create two classes for the RFM segmentation since, being high recency is bad, while high frequency and monetary value is good.
# Arguments (x = value, p = recency, monetary_value, frequency, k = quartiles dict)
def RClass(x, p, d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 1
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 2
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]:
        return 3
    else:
        return 4


# Arguments (x = value, p = recency, monetary_value, frequency, k = quartiles dict)
def FMClass(x, p, d):
    if x <= d[p][0.25]:
        return 4
    elif x <= d[p][0.50]:
        return 3
    elif x <= d[p][0.75]:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: does the variable `quantiles` have the key `"monetary_value"`? I suspect based on the error that it doesn't but should, so the question is why does it not? does your csv have the column "grand_total" because the script kind of assumes it does.

Comment: thanks for making me take a look back at "grand total" in the csv  this fixed it -- the issue was that I had negative numbers in the column without realizing it! Thank you.